# Looking at converting, have some questions

Tags: non-muslim, conversion

I am considering converting to Islam and have several questions.

Is my name permissible, or should I change it due to it having un-Islamic meanings? Todd means fox, clever or wily (intending to be deceitful), and Christopher means Christ-bearer. I've been told that Todd shouldn't be used because of it's connotation, and Christopher is too Christian.  Also, should I go through the legal change process or just use my new name like a nickname?

My other question is hair on men, my hair is long, it is past my shoulders but is neat and kept clean, am I commanded to cut it if I convert? My beard is already in and long.  I've heard I should cut or not as long as it's neat.  Also, what about piercings?  I have lip and ear.

Comment: Salam and welcome ton Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider learning more about our site and the stacke exchange model by taking our 2 min [tour] and visiting our [help]. As for your concern I also strongly recommend you to search here by tag [tag:conversion].

Comment: For naming issue you can look these: [Is it ok to add a typical secular western (non-christian) first name to my name to reduce discrimination?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/is-it-ok-to-add-a-typical-secular-western-non-christian-first-name-to-my-name) and this: [Giving an English name to a child in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/giving-an-english-name-to-a-child-in-islam) and this:[Changing my name upon conversion](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/changing-my-name-upon-conversion)

Comment: For hair: [How long are men allowed to have their hair?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11714/how-long-are-men-allowed-to-have-their-hair)

Comment: And about shahadah, Islam suggest to believe one and only God and his messengers. IMHO If you are accepting this, you are already a believer, you can gladly say it. A believer can have doubts about other topics in Islam. These topics need time to learn. You can learn them anytime you want. However if this doubts make you not believe, feel comfortable to take time to say shahadah.

Comment: So it's OK to have my hair long, but it's better to keep it short?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rough answer without any evidence (I'll try to give some later):

- IMO Todd as a name is OK the bigger problem would be with Christopher, as for the ruling on whether you'll have your new name as a nickname or if you need to go through a legal change process. I'd say the tendency would be for the change process but I honestly have no backup for that.
- Hair length for a Muslim man is not a problem the most important is a clean appearance. I think I've read somewhere that even sahaba had long hair. Pearcings should be a problem if you want to convert you should take them away as Islam doesn't allow "harming" oneself!
- This is a difficult question: From one perspective it is the best if your conversion came from your insight and faith. On the other hand some may say as we don't know when we will die, it could be best to convert as dying as Muslim would mean a good chance to enter Jannah. Especially as you already knew about Islam. So you should try to learn and check and ask and I hope you'll make the right decision.

Comment: So I'm thinking I would need to choose a new name based on here and other sources, should I take another "Western" name or should I take an Arabic name that would identify me as a Muslim?

Comment: @ToddChristopher I think most Muslims would recommend you a Muslim name.  But you know your circumstances best and you'll have the choice. My recommendation would be something like Kilise quoted a name that may be western but sounds also familiar to Muslims.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer your questions about the name and the hair.

Consider this answer: 
[Is the name “Christine” haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/is-the-name-christine-haram)

About your name: "Early Christians used it as a metaphorical name, expressing that they carried Christ in their hearts. "... Christ means "the chosen one".

I would draw the same conclusion as in the answer to the related question (Is the name “Christine” haram?).  I.e that your name is not haram.
Also by changing your name to a arabic name, you might just make life harder for yourself. So in the times we are living in, I wouldn't recommend it. If you insist on changing it I would recommend changing it to something like Elias (Ilyas in arabic).

The hair shouldn't be a problem. In fact there are hadiths that the Prophet (saw) used to have long hair. It was kind of a fashion in that time.

Answer (score 2):

Assalamu 'alaikum.

Like the above answers:

- Name is not a problem if it doesn't have non-islamic or bad meaning.
- Hair is not even a problem. Even Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) also had hair like your's. It was very long. about the beard. keep it, if it is neet and suits you. but be beautiful. about the piercing. You should take it. You can't be like a muslim with piercings
- You are a muslim. Since you believe that Islam is the true religion.

Welcome to Islam. May Allah give you good health and victory in your research.

And can you share us your research about Islam. It will be useful for us to tell about Islam to non-muslims